# software center stop working?

Tags: software-center

```
2013-04-03 19:25:58,551 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-04-03 19:25:58,561 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-04-03 19:25:59,468 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-04-03 19:25:59,476 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py', 51, 'find_module')'
2013-04-03 19:25:59,476 - root - ERROR - Could not find any typelib for LaunchpadIntegration
2013-04-03 19:25:59,585 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-04-03 19:25:59,590 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()

** (software-center:5904): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libwebkitgtk-3.0.soso: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py:42: Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type `void'
  self.webkit = WebKit.WebView()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 182, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1387, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1325, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 151, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 139, in init_view
    SoftwarePane.init_view(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/softwarepane.py", line 161, in init_view
    self.cache)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 884, in __init__
    self._layout_page()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py", line 1219, in _layout_page
    self.videoplayer = VideoPlayer()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.webkit = WebKit.WebView()
TypeError: could not get a reference to type class
```

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and do this

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

then try again.